# Accessing specific child type method in arraylist of type parent without typecasting, creation of child type is only known at runtime

Tags: java

I have the following parent class:

```
public class Employee {
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

And 2 child class which extends parent:

```
public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee {
    private double salary;

    public FullTimeEmployee(String name, double salary) {
        super(name);
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary*2;
    }
}

public class PartTimeEmployee extends Employee {
    private double salary;

    public PartTimeEmployee(String name, double salary) {
        super(name);
        this.salary = salary;
    }   

    public double getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }   
}
```

The scenario:
I am using an ArrayList to contain information about employees. The **ArrayList is created at the start of the program**, and the **type of employee** being added into the Arraylist is a child extending parent and **only known at runtime** through user's input

```
public class EmployeeApplication {

    public static void displayInfo(Employee employee) {
        
        // How do I access the method getSalary() that belong to the specific type determined on runtime?
        System.out.println(employee.getSalary()); //  <--- ???
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner(System.in);
            
        System.out.println("Type of employee to add into arraylist: ");
        String userInput = keyboardInput.nextLine();
        
        // ArrayList to contain information about employees
        ArrayList<Employee> employeeAL = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        
        // Type of employee being created and added into ArrayList is dynamic and only known at run time based on user input
        if(userInput.equals("full")) {
            employeeAL.add(new FullTimeEmployee("John", 1000));
        }
        else {
            employeeAL.add(new PartTimeEmployee("John", 500));
        }
        
        displayInfo(employeeAL.get(0));
        
        keyboardInput.close();      
    }
}
```

Now the question:
how do I access the method getSalary() belonging to the specific child type that was determined on runtime? Since the object retrieved from the ArrayList is a parent type. Please note that the **salary attribute only belongs to the child class**.

My current implementation has me checking for the child type, typecasting it into that child type, and finally accessing the method belonging to the child.

I am **trying to avoid typecasting** because I believe I am doing things wrongly with regards to good Java coding practise. I'm missing something here but I just don't know what

Another method which I have thought about is to **implement the method getSalary() in the parent class** and **overriding it in the child class**, this way, I don't have to typecast but I don't know if this is the right practice since the **salary attribute has got no relation** with Employee at all:

```
// Parent
public class Employee {
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    // ADDED THIS <----
    public double getSalary() {
        return 0.0;
    }
}

// Child
public class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee {
    private double salary;

    public FullTimeEmployee(String name, double salary) {
        super(name);
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    // ADDED THIS <----
    @Override
    public double getSalary() {
        return salary*2;
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrongly and what is the best Java coding practice?

Comment: Yes adding the method to the superclass is the right path here (or introducing an interface). If you never create Employee objects then you should consider making that class abstract and you can also make the getSalary method abstract

Comment: please don't use inexact types for anything that has to do with money. ever.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Can you provide a simple example please? Employee will never be created, but it will be used as a type for creation of the ArrayList to hold employee information

Comment: [Learning the Java Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) explains OOP concepts in java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement Employee as abstract and add getSalary() as an abstract method which forces subclasses of Employee to implement that method

```
public abstract class Employee {
    private String name;

    public Employee(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    abstract protected double getSalary();
}
```

Comment: I would suggest changing the access modifier of the constructor to `protected`, to ensure that only derived classes can invoke it.